# How to copy file content on Wildfly 10 server?

Tags: java, file, file-upload, wildfly

I want to upload image, and return filepath to save in database so i can later diplay that image.

I am using Primefaces UploadeFile. But when i try to upload file, i get file not found Exception. I am propably making error in path, but i don't know where those files are saved.

I have method that performs file upload.

Essentialy i generate unique file name and try to copy it to location.

```
Date date = new Date();
String filename = author.getSlug() + "-" + date.getTime() + "." + FilenameUtils.getExtension(image.getFileName());
File path = new File("/uploads/authors", filename);

InputStream input = image.getInputstream();

Files.copy(input, path.toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

This code throws file not found exception.

Comment: Does the `/uploads/authors` directory exist?

Comment: The error is no JSF or Primefaces specific.

Comment: I thought it would be relative to application path, but obvioulsy it isn't. It hits absoulte path on file system. So what i did, is aded dedicated folder in data folder of wildfly and added custom configuration in wildfly that when i hit `http://localhost:8080/Bookstore/uploads` it would link to that created folder. Where Bookstore is my context path of the application. But i am not satisfied with that solution since it would not work without server hack. Is there a better, more common best practice to do this?